# How can I find the item id related to the maximum resource by year in SQL (postgres)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to run a SQL query that seems easy but I don't understand what mechanism I should use to achieve this.
I have the following table:

```
| id | playcount | release_date |
| -- | --------- | ------------ |
| 1  | 47712     | 2019-12-27   |
| 2  | 626778    | 2017-07-23   |
| 3  | 827091    | 2019-09-12   |
| 4  | 66419     | 2015-09-05   |
| 5  | 58627     | 2016-09-12   |
| 6  | 60272     | 2017-09-06   |
| 7  | 1762582   | 2017-10-07   |
| 8  | 11280     | 2016-10-12   |
| 9  | 30890     | 2019-10-29   |
| 10 | 715173    | 2019-07-02   |
```

I would like to find which id holds the maximum `playcount` per year.
In this example, the id that has the maximum `playcount` in 2019 is `3`.

And I'm looking for the following output:

```
playcount_table
| year | playcount | id |
| ---- | --------- | -- |
| 2019 | 827091    | 3  |
| 2017 | 1762582   | 7  |
| 2016 | 58627     | 5  |
| 2015 | 66419     | 4  |
```

I succeeded to get the maximum playcount by year with the following query:

```sql
select to_char(date_trunc('year', TO_DATE(p_table.release_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as year,
       max(p_table.playcount) as playcounts
from playcount_table as p_table
group by year;
```

But I can't retrieve the `id` related to this max `playcount`.

Can you help me with this ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(year FROM release_date)
                                 ORDER BY playcount DESC) rn
    FROM playcount_table
)

SELECT
    EXTRACT(year FROM release_date) year
    playcount,
    id
FROM cte
WHERE
    rn = 1
ORDER BY
    EXTRACT(year FROM release_date) DESC;
```

If a given year could have two or more records tied for the greatest play count, and you would want to report both of them, then replace `ROW_NUMBER` above with `RANK`.

We might also be able to use `DISTINCT ON` here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (EXTRACT(year FROM release_date))
    EXTRACT(year FROM release_date),
    playcount,
    id
FROM playcount_table
ORDER BY
    EXTRACT(year FROM release_date),
    playcount DESC;
```

Comment: @LouisonGitzinger . . . `DISTINCT ON` is the right solution in Postgres.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But, I would argue, an analytic function-based solution still has merit here (e.g. the OP wanting to use `RANK` to retain ties for first place).